# Divergence of a tensor field in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I know it is possible to take the divergence of a vector field in `sympy`. For example:

```
>>> from sympy.physics.vector import ReferenceFrame
>>> from sympy.physics.vector import divergence
>>> R = ReferenceFrame('R')
>>> vfield = 3*R[0]**2*R.x+2*R[1]*R.y
>>> divergence(vfield,R)
6*R_x + 2
```

However, it it possible to take the divergence of a *tensor* field? I have not seen anything addressing this in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: `sympy.physics.vector` is being rewritten into `sympy.vector`.

I appears that the vector module does not really support tensor fields, but you could use N-dimensional arrays, for example:

```
In [6]: ta = Array([[Function("f_{0}{1}".format(j,i))(x,y,z) for i in range(1,4)
   ...: ] for j in range(1,4)])

In [7]: ta
Out[7]: 
⎡f₁₁(x, y, z)  f₁₂(x, y, z)  f₁₃(x, y, z)⎤
⎢                                        ⎥
⎢f₂₁(x, y, z)  f₂₂(x, y, z)  f₂₃(x, y, z)⎥
⎢                                        ⎥
⎣f₃₁(x, y, z)  f₃₂(x, y, z)  f₃₃(x, y, z)⎦

In [9]: tensorcontraction(derive_by_array(ta, (x, y, z)), (0, 1))
Out[9]: 
⎡∂                  ∂                  ∂                 ∂                  ∂ 
⎢──(f₁₁(x, y, z)) + ──(f₂₁(x, y, z)) + ──(f₃₁(x, y, z))  ──(f₁₂(x, y, z)) + ──
⎣∂x                 ∂y                 ∂z                ∂x                 ∂y

                 ∂                 ∂                  ∂                  ∂    
(f₂₂(x, y, z)) + ──(f₃₂(x, y, z))  ──(f₁₃(x, y, z)) + ──(f₂₃(x, y, z)) + ──(f₃
                 ∂z                ∂x                 ∂y                 ∂z   

           ⎤
₃(x, y, z))⎥
           ⎦
```

In point 6 a rank 2 array is created, in point 9 the same array is derived by another array `(x, y, z)`, thus creating a rank 3 array (shape is 3x3x3). At this point `tensorcontraction` contracts the 1st and 2nd axes, reducing the result to a rank 1 array (with 3 elements).